# Is there a method to retrieve the list of nodes & edges under a border router?

Tags: openthread

I'm planning to build a network visualization tool for open thread networks. Does anyone know a way to use wpanctl to get all the nodes and hops under the current network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design, no Thread device maintains state about all devices within its Thread network. As a result, wpanctl does not provide a single command to provide a listing of all nodes in the network.

What you can do is get a listing of neighboring devices using the following command:

```
wpanctl get thread:NeighborTable
```